# How fix the position the asp.net diagnostics trace on a page

Tags: asp.net

I use the [diagnostics trace](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82290/Step-by-Step-Guide-to-Trace-the-ASP-NET-Applicatio) on one of my asp.net pages. It works somewhat, but the trace data is drawn all over my page: This makes it impossible to use the page any more, nor to properly read the trace.

I use a master page. However i guess it has something to do with the css styles, but how to do without changing the customers styles, and on all pages, with probably different styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody seems to have this problem, except me? At least almost: The [blog of Jeffrey McManus](http://blog.jeffreymcmanus.com/29/using-css-p-with-aspnet-trace-mode/) helped me out.

I now use a modified approach on the master page where I put

```
<!-- styles to make the trace output work-->
<style>
  #__asptrace  
  {
    position: relative;
    top: 900px;
    left: 0px;
  }
</style>
```

Play a bit with the top value and the position type and you are set.